# Communication between 2 web services on 2 systems

Tags: web-services, netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish

We have a java ws deployed on Glassfish talking to another java ws deployed on glassfish (both are Java EE 5 and both are being developed on netbeans 6.7.1).  So neither of these ws use SSL, but when the main ws calls the other we are getting this error:

```
WSTX-COORDINATOR-3005: registerResponse sent to EPR '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><EndpointReference xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"><Address>https://trinity2.its.local:8181/__wstx-services/wscoor/coordinator/registerResponse</Address><ReferenceParameters><jaxws:objectId xmlns:jaxws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/xml/ns/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">4e470037-57c9-4903-9b32-fafc6da84ec7</jaxws:objectId></ReferenceParameters></EndpointReference>' failed.  activityId 'uuid:WSCOOR-SUN-2ade62a8-d476-474b-9b9d-a0c1fdeb069f' and msg 'uuid:41c6e179-af20-47da-bbfd-e73519000765'. Nested exception: 'HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target'
HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:134)
```

How can we keep glassfish from trying to talk to each other via SSL?  When we do a regular java app that works as a client to the 2nd WS it works fine, so it seems it something that glassfish does.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a partial answer to my question.  So in netbeans I opened up the server's wsdl in the client project and deleted all of the policy information.

So this:

```
<operation name="jobNote">
<ns216:PolicyReference xmlns:ns216="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" URI="#MetaPortBinding_jobNote_WSAT_Policy"></ns216:PolicyReference>
<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
```

became this:

And it worked fine... Is there anything I can do to strip this policy information automatically, I am guessing through the build?